# Send email using PHPMailer with empty content

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email using phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer to send an email via SMTP.  There is a requirement that the email has no content in the body, only an attatchment.

If I neglect to include **$body** or set **$body = ''** then I get an error message telling me that **'Mailer Error: Message body empty'**

Does anybody know of a workaround or a way to force PHPMailer to accept a blank body>?

Comment: how about `$body = ' ';` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force phpmailer to send mail with empty body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251753/force-phpmailer-to-send-mail-with-empty-body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:
`$body = " ";` or `$body = ";nbsp";`

Answer (score 1):

It's just a class so make your own subclass, copy the method that throws that error and comment out the check for it. That way you don't need to touch the library.