# Force phpmailer to send mail with empty body

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I need to send an pdf file as attachment to a FAX gateway using phpMailer. If this email has a body, the fax will have a second page with this text.

By saying:

```
$mail->Body = "";
```

php Mailer returns `Message body empty`

How can I force phpMailer to send emails without a body message?

Here the complete code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$emailto = $_POST['sendto'].'@gateway.provider.xy';
$pdf_filename = 'PDF_list_'.date('dmY').'.pdf';
/*
STMP Auth...
*/
$mail->From = $fmail;
$mail->FromName = $row_firma['company'];
$mail->AddAddress($emailto);
$mail->AddAttachment($pdf_filename);
$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->Body = "";
$mail->AltBody = "";
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Try with &nbsp or whitsapce;

Comment: use null to initialize body variable

Comment: both doesn't work. With null it´s the same message as in my post and with &nbsp or whitespace; the fax got a second empty page

Comment: set your mail format to html and use "<br/>" as body. I hope this will work

Comment: same here: Message will be sent but as a second empty fax page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy fix:

```
$mail->AllowEmpty = true;
```

Comment: I know this post is old but I used the `AllowEmpty` option and it's perfect, I can send mail without a body. But... But in the mail source I have a `Content-Type:text/plain` with 2 characters 10 (0a)
Is there a method to send mail without text/plain...?

Comment: I think that's a property empty body, because a message is defined as the headers, 2 line breaks (those 2 chars – I'm guessing you're using PHP mail() mode, as otherwise it would be 4 chars for 2 x CRLF), and then the body, so an empty message is the headers then the 2 line breaks, which is what you have. I'm not sure you can easily suppress the content type header though. Maybe subclass to remove it, given that this is an edge case?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed to remove the header I had to create a specific class. And it works with this "personal" class