# PHPMailer - Send Attachments without body

Tags: phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send PDF attachments to an online fax machine.  My problem is when I send a "body" through even if it's just a 'space' it will add a separate page since it sees the character.  Is there a way to send mail **WITHOUT** a body?  If i try sending without a body i just get the error "*Mailer Error: Message body empty*" :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force phpmailer to send mail with empty body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251753/force-phpmailer-to-send-mail-with-empty-body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update version of PHPMailer. This issue was listed as a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmailer/bugs/334/)  some time ago. It appears it was fixed in newer versions.

Comment: This is correct - you need to set `$mail->AllowEmpty = true;`, docs [here](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_AllowEmpty).